# running node.js API

Tags: node.js, api

> I'm currently trying to run node.js API on my system with Oracle client 11g 64-bit installed and node version 6.9.2 64-bit but it throws the below error:

```
Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js
6.9.2 (win32, x64) Node.js require() error was:   DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded:
"E:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN\oci.dll is not the
 correct architecture". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/
 installation.html#windows for help
```

It also prompts to `check the availability of 64-bit Oracle client libraries in the PATH environment variable`, which I have already validated.

```
Node-oracledb installation instructions:
https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html You must have
64-bit Oracle client libraries in your PATH environment variable. If
you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the
Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html A
Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributable suitable for your Oracle
client library version must be available.
```

Also `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistribitable 64bit 2012,2013,2015` are also installed.

Need help troubleshooting this problem as I do not know where is the link missing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have Oracle DB installed in your system?
2. Is Oracle client libraries installed in your system and added in your PATH environment variable?
3. Is Microsoft Visual Studio installed in your system?

Please check above dependencies then try again.

Comment: Oracle 11g 64-bit is installed also the client libraries are installed and the PATH environment variable is also updated. Microsoft Visual Studio is also installed